# How to modify a <staticText> element in a JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I've an xml that I restore from my Data base containing jasperreports. Here's an excerpt:

```
<staticText>......<text><![CDATA[Entidad Bancaria:]]></text></staticText>
```

I want to programatically substitute the **content** of the CDATA element and then regenerate the JasperReport, but I found that the API doesn't allow to do this (or it's too difficult to figure out how). So I tried to convert the jasper xml into a string, from string to Inputstream (to match the signature of JasperFillManager.fillReport() method), but the compile fails... Does anyone know how to accomplish this in a correct way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Static text isn't made to be changed programmatically. Why not just change the `staticText` to a `textField` and then use a parameter? Change the xml to:

```
<textField><textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{banc}]]></textFieldExpression></textField>
```

Then set the value of `banc` programatically and pass it to `fillReport()`

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something like that too. I'll try it. Thank you!